# Swift 3 - How to get JSON Objects with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I want to use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON for my REST api.I have accessed the root json but i can't access the objects of json. What is the best way to parse it correctly combining these two libraries?

My JSON:-

```
[
{
    "ID": 2,
    "Nm": "ABC",
    "Descr": null,
    "BeenCnt": "9",
    "FavCnt": "9",
    "ImgPath": "pathtoimage",
    "TypeID": 4,
    "Type": null,
    "DayCnt": 5,
    "NightCnt": 4,
    "ValidDate": null,
    "UsrCommentCnt": null,
    "TourDates": null,
    "CityList": [
        {
            "KeyID": null,
            "ID": 1,
            "Data": "abc"
        },
        {
            "KeyID": null,
            "ID": 12,
            "Data": "abc"
        }
    ],
    "Seller": {
        "ID": 1,
        "Nm": "abc",
        "CityNm": null,
        "StateNm": null,
        "CommentCnt": null,
        "BeenCnt": null,
        "Add": null,
        "PackList": []
    },
    "Chrg": {
        "ID": 0,
        "PaxDetail": "Per Person",
        "PkgMode": null,
        "Amt": 15000,
        "AmtCurrID": 2,
        "AmtCurr": null,
        "ChargeSeq": 0
    },
    "ItineraryList": []
}
```

I want 'Chrg' to populate in my `UICollectionView`.

What i am trying in coding:-

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in


        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJSONVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyJSONVar[].arrayObject
            {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                print(self.arrRes)
            }

            if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                self.collection.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
```

My `UICollectionViewCell` :-

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PackagesCell
    var dict = arrRes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    var charge = dict["Chrg"] as! Dictionary<String,String>
    cell.amtLbl.text = charge["Amt"] as? String
    cell.NmLbl.text = dict["Nm"] as? String
    cell.nightsLbl.text = String(Int((dict["NightCnt"] as! Int64)))
    cell.dayLbl.text = String(Int(dict["DayCnt"] as! Int64))

    cell.perPersonLbl.text = dict["PaxDetail"] as? String
    cell.validTillLbl.text = dict["ValidDate"] as? String
    cell.iternaryListLbl.text = dict["CityList"]?["Data"] as? String
    cell.cmtLbl.text = dict["BeenCnt"] as? String
    cell.beenCmtLbl.text = dict["FavCnt"] as? String
    self.id = String(dict["ID"] as! Int64)
    let ImgPath = dict["ImgPath"] as? String
    let fulURL = "\(self.site + ImgPath!)"
    let newURL = fulURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "/")
    let newwURL = newURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "png", with: "jpg")
    cell.img.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:newwURL),  placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is better way to parse JSON

**Simply typecast it:**

```
if let jsonArray = responseData.result.value as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> {
     print("Json Response: \(jsonArray)") // serialized json response
     self.arrRes = jsonArray
}
if let arrCityList = self.arrRes[0]["CityList"] as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> {
     print(arrCityList)// You can populate the table from city list
}
```

Comment: Hoe to use it in `UICollectionView`?

Comment: I want to populate `UICollectionView` Items with 'Chrg' can you help me out?

Comment: it print your json `print("Json Response: \(jsonArray)")` ?

Comment: Now you have your JSON in jsonArray with the swift Array collection you can use it as you are using.

Comment: `cell.amtLbl.text = dict["Amt"] as? String` unable to get value

Comment: Try this `let charge = dict["Chrg"] as? Dictionary<String,String>
cell.amtLbl.text = charge["Amt"] as? String`

Comment: If this does not work let me know and update your question!

Comment: Update your question'

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: `print(dict)`   `print(charge)` let me know what you get!

Comment: Thanks it worked by deleting `as? Dictionary<String,String>` from Declaration

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I want to access CityList and populate my `UICollectionViewCell` Please Help me

Comment: It shows an error at jsonArray that it is undeclared identifier

Comment: replace it with `self.arrRes[0]`

Comment: And how to use it in `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: You have to ask in other question with some code of your collection datasource

Comment: Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a model for the above mentioned json,then it becomes quite easy for you to populate the data in collectionview

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Here's how i usually go about it.

```
....
let jsonResponse = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
var firstName = (jsonResponse["result"]["name"]).string?;
var lastName = (jsonResponse["result"]["surname"]).string?;
var emails = (jsonResponse["result"]["emails"]).array?;

//make your object or object array here using the values above. e.g
var cic = CustomItemForCollection( name : firstName , surname: lastName, emailArr: emails )
...
```

There's quite a few types that JSON from SwiftyJson can produce , what essentially this does is it's type casting it for you.